# Magento 1.9.2.4 File Was Not Uploaded

Tags: magento-1.9, error, image, magento1.9.2.4

[image]

Hey, I just installed Magento 1.9.2.4 and try to upload a new product all goes well but when I try to upload an image it uploads to 100% and then I am getting a " File was not uploaded." error.

Could someone help?

Thanks,

Denys

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on your media folder? Most likely you don't have correct permissions on that folder.

/media and /var should be 700/600.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: I have 
Owner: rwx 
Group: r-x 
Others: r-x 
for both folders

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you, you can use this extension because I was already facing issues like you. but after using this extension my issue was resolve and now it's working fine.

Extension link: https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

Answer (score -1):

I had to delete

throw new Exception`('File was not uploaded.', $code);`

for `Uploader.php`

and its works perfectly